# Answering portable barbecue question with a wiki list-answer

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, community-wiki

Does it make sense to answer Q: [In which European countries can I use disposable barbecues in summer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47768/in-which-european-countries-can-i-use-disposable-barbecues-in-summer) with a community-wiki list-answer? If not then it should probably be closed as too broad.

Comment: Strongly endorsed if the question is scoped to include the EEA.

Comment: Is it even answerable at the national level? In the US I imagine this is something that could be regulated all the way down at the local municipality level.

Comment: It's unanswerable in the general case -- for example those barbecues are perfectly legal (and ubiquitous) in the UK, except for where they aren't. The exceptions go all the way down to the local landowner, or (very) local government in the case of public land. Additionally exceptions can be made based on time and other events on-going. I'm sure there are also places were it's generally allowed except when the weather is such that there's a risk of forest fires. "How can I find out if it's OK to use a disposable barbecue in a certain place" is probably a better, answerable, question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hindsight I think the question might be too broad, since the regulations will vary not only between countries, but probably also between regional and council authorities. This is the case for example in Italy, where [barbecues were recently banned in public parks (from June to Semptember) in Roman by the mayor himself](http://roma.corriere.it/notizie/cronaca/15_maggio_19/divieto-fumo-parchi-pubblici-ma-solo-giugno-settembre-9e11e14e-fe2c-11e4-bed4-3ff992d01df9.shtml) citing the, albeit realistic, risk of fires:

> Niente più sigarette e barbecue «fai da te» a Villa Borghese o a villa Ada e nelle altre aree verdi e parchi pubblici della Capitale dal 15 giugno fino al 30 settembre.

Whereas [the Milan Parco Nord regulations explicitly allow barbecues in the dedicated areas](http://www.parconord.milano.it/regolamento).:

> #### Art.41-Fuochi all'aperto
>
> E' vietato accendere fuochi all'aperto tranne che per i barbecue limitatamente alle aree a tal fine attrezzate e comunque curandone il totale e perfetto spegnimento al termine dell'uso.

It is safe to assume that such differences must exist between various other parks, let alone cities.

For all these these reason I have voted to close the question as `too broad`, since it would seem that public barbecues are regulated at the local level, more than at the national one, at least in some European countries.